# Display issues on iPad/Safari when using minified JS

Tags: angularjs, safari, minify, ipad-2

This is a really strange issue that I've been trying to figure out for several days with no luck. It only happens on slow iOS devices, it doesn't happen every time, and it only happens when using minified JS code (both Angular and my app code).

When the issue occurs it looks as though Angular just stops processing the code and leaves the "mustaches" on the page as can be seen in the attached screen shot. If I switch to using the non-minified versions of my JS files as well as the non-minified angular files then it works just fine. I've used Safari developer tools to debug this issue, but there are no exceptions thrown and it looks like all the data is being set correctly on the scope.

Any help/ideas with this issue will be greatly appreciated.

[image: "mustaches" shown instead of correct data]

Comment: This only happens on Safari. If I use Chrome on the same iPad I cannot reproduce it.